# A separator (?) in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

In this picture I have these two line separators, I don't know how to delete them or how to create them.

How can I do that? If I want to remove them or only add them in one specific place?

Comment: Can you share a link to the file?

Comment: They are probably paragraph rules. [This may be of use](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/rule-after-paragraph-in-2010-version/99a43352-3d7f-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5)

Answer (score 1):

These are borders.
It is possible they are table borders but it is more likely that they are paragraph borders.

In most installations, if you press three equal signs and then Enter, you will get these under Autoformat As You Type.

I turn that option off, though.

Select the (blank) paragraph above and beyond these and under Borders and Shading, select no border to turn them off.

To get them, try the three = signs and Enter.

You can also go under Borders on the Paragraph Group of the Home tab and at the bottom use More Borders and Shading. Pick your border weight, type and placement in this dialog.

To see more about this, see Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's [page on Troublesome Lines and Borders](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TroublesomeLines.htm#Borders).